# CMS installed in an IIS server

Tags: php, mysql, iis, tinymce

I have a `CMS` for a client installed in an `IIS server`.
The problem is, the `CMS` doesn't upload the images for the blog posts.
Also, the friendly URL's for the posts doesn't work.

**For example** if you write a post with the title "El mejor camión" the URL should be `www.ejemplo.com/blog/elmerjocamion` but the `CMS` makes the URL `www.ejemplo.com/blog/elmejorcami` and the URL doesn't work.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: you should say the name of your CMS.
and say more details about your problems.

Comment: the CMS is custom made by a company that doesn't give support anymore. It uses php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the example you've given it seems that you're CMS did not like the letter ó, as the URL was created upto that point ok. Try using 'o' for that article but otherwise we will need to know which CMS to help you further with the language localization. Check the characters used in the images titles as that may well solve that issue too.

Comment: In the browser console it gives failure related to this: 
        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

Comment: Are those files found ok? Was the url error caused by the character used? Your title does not identify a specific issue, let's fix that one first then you can change the title to 'Unsupported custom CMS can't upload images'. If you manually place the images in an expected location can you get them to render?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand very well what you mean. I'm not a developer, I just got this problem because the company I hired for the project doesn't get support anymore.
Apparently those files are not in the project, something like they are created when you upload an image using the CMS.

Comment: And yes, the client is manually placing the images and they render. But it's supposed to be done by the CMS.

Comment: I was asking first if you had been able to publish by removing the letter ó. I was then commenting that the title of this question is not very clear, sorry if that confused the matter. Finally regarding those files, do you have a folder called 'lists' in your project? I would guess there should be those js (eg. image_list.js ) files in there.

Comment: Yes I was able to publish removing the ó, but it should work with ó letter replacing automatically with o.
I have a lists folder in the plugins folder of the tiny_mce folder, but those files aren't there.
Sorry if the title is confusing, what title should I use then?